# (Wordpress, Cryon) Incorrect arguments for 'wp-load' Solution

Tags: wordpress, plugins

If You have installed Cryon plugin, and got a error message in ajax request:
Incorrect arguments for 'wp-load'

Answer (score 0):

You can check that You have defined ABSPATH in PHP code, if not, here is low level solution:

Edit: cryon_te_content.php

line: 16

code:

```
require_once('../../crayon_wp.class.php');
//crayon_die_if_not_php($_GET['wp_load'], 'wp-load');
//require_once ($_GET['wp_load']);
require_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
```

That's all folks! :)